# How to understand 'by' in "until by..."

Tags: grammar, meaning

From Andrew Radford. (2004). English Syntax: An Introduction. p.4.:

> From this point on, there is a rapid expansion in their grammatical
> development, until **by** the age of around 30 months they have typically
> acquired most of the inflections and core grammatical constructions
> used in English, and are able to produce adult-like sentences such as
> *Where’s Mummy gone? What’s Daddy doing? Can we go to the zoo, Daddy?*
> etc. (though occasional morphological and syntactic errors persist
> until the age of four years or so – e.g. *We goed there with Daddy,
> What we can do?* etc.).

Could it be rewritten as 'until the age of around 30 months when....'?

"until" is often followed by a specific point in time, but here the time is modified by "by". Does "by" imply "at"?

Comment: This is a dreadful passage full of bad grammar and incorrect punctuation. Don't try to learn English from this.

Comment: Doesn't seem so bad to me, though it's rather a rambling sentence. The sense is "...until they have acquired most of the inflections... (which, typically, has happened by the age of 30 months)".

Comment: The passage is fine. **by** when used with a time-expression can mean "not later than".  If children typically learn something "by the age of 24 months", they typically learn it "not later than 24 months" after they're born.  Compare  "Arrive by 3PM or you won't find a seat."

Comment: The prepositional phrase headed by **by** is a parenthetical remark and could be set off with some punctuation or parentheses.  Compare "The balloon gets bigger and bigger as it is filled with air, until (by the time it has expanded to ten times its original size) it bursts."

Comment: The parenthetical remark could be relocated: *From this point on, there is a rapid expansion in their grammatical development, until they have typically acquired (by the age of around 30 months) most of the inflections and core grammatical constructions used in English, and are able to produce adult-like sentences such as Where’s Mummy gone?"*

Comment: @Astralbee: I can't see anything wrong with the cited text, and the writer is after all a native Anglophone professor of linguistics. It seems concise and clear to me - what exactly is it you're finding fault with? I don't suppose Radford is particularly interested in how English *learners* deal with his text, though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I look forward to your answer.

Comment: @Astralbee: Why? I just want to know what you think is defective about the cited text.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I suspect TimR is right that "*by the age of around 30 months*" is parenthetical. The lack of commas surrounding it make the grammar incorrect, as the OP has noticed. I'm surprised that got past the editors at Cambridge University Press.

Comment: @gotube: I think that's nonsense! Semantically speaking, the element *"by the age of around 30 months"* isn't remotely "parenthetical" - it's a crucial part of the meaning of the entire paragraph. Just because *syntactically* you could "justify" an alternative sequence and/or punctuation doesn't mean you *should*. Personally I think TimR's rearrangement is inferior to the original, but that's not the issue here. At best, that's just a matter of stylistic preference. I'm concerned with challenging Astralbee's totally unjustifiable assertion about "bad grammar and incorrect punctuation".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little worrying that a book about syntax should contain such convoluted English.

The cause of your particular concern is poor, or maybe even incorrect, punctuation. If we move the second comma after "until", it is clear that "by the age of around 30 months" is a parenthetical phrase. Once that's done, it is easy to see that "until" is a conjunction that links the subordinate clause "they have typically...".

> From this point on, there is a rapid expansion in their grammatical development until, by the age of around 30 months, they have typically acquired most of the inflections and core grammatical constructions used in English...

The sentence could also be made clearer as you suggested, but it would be much clearer to split this mega-sentence into several shorter sentences.

Answer (score 0):

**by the age of around 30 months**

establishes a limit of around 30 months that you can then use in a comparison.

It's an extremely common usage. Other examples:

> They are fully integrated by Year 3.
> By the time it takes me to run one mile, he will have run 10.
> You have to get there by 5:00 to get a seat.